# Best way to setup small local network to send commands to connected devices

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

**I know that this question is fuzzy but I'm hoping some helpful soul could give me some pointers on possible solutions.**

I'm need to setup a small local network of rasberry pis that I need to be able to send commands to by a central computer and I'm not sure about what the best way to manage these devices is. The central computer needs to know the ip addresses of the connected devices and I'm trying to figure out how to handle these. The network is not connected to internet and is only used for the raspberry pis and some Brightsign players.

A friend told me that a solution would be to have static DHCP and a DNS that used the device names for accessing the connected devices. But from what I understand, this would mean that I need to manually add the ip address and device name to the DNS? Or is there some way to automate this to let the DHCP configure the DNS? I have a large number of devices and would like to be able to automate as much as possible to avoid errors.

Another solution would be to use some kind of discovery service to search for connected devices. But this feels like an overkill since the connected devices will not change very often.

Comment: If you set up fixed addresses, either in the DHCP server or in the individual devices (make sure you choose addresses outside the DHCP pool), you can access the devices by IP address. You can additionally add these fixed addresses to `hosts` files to give names to the IPs without needing to use DNS.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution here would be to skip DNS and DHCP all together and only use static IPs. This would save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: But that would mean that I need to document the ip addresses somewhere. Wouldn't it be better to let the DHCP to assign the static ip adresses?

Answer (score 0):

The best way do to it is through software like chef or puppet.

Issue a command, and it is replicated to all the clients.  They are usually python based.

https://www.chef.io/chef/
https://puppet.com/